# xlwings: "Run main" cannot find filepath?

Tags: xlwings

I'm new to xlwings - started with trying to understand basics but it is not working ...

Created .py and .xlsx files (with same name) in same folder; inserted basic "Hello World" code as main() in .py file.
Using `Run main` button in Excel file gives:

```
Run-time error '53': File not found
```

Tried to trouble-shoot why this could be: debugging via VBA interface found that the routine was searching in the folder `C:\Users\MYNAME\AppData\LocalTemp\` (not the project's folder) and coming up with a very long .log  filename which changes each time I attempt to run it (eg. `xlwings-374ABEE7-4C51-8622-AB5B-D42C5294C2B8.log`)

Is this a bug which needs to be corrected? or have I done something incorrectly?

Using:
Windows 10;
MS Office 365;
xlwings ver: 0.19.5